# Keypress for node.js crashing on numbers

Tags: node.js

I'm pretty new to node.js and I'm having a problem with keypress while working with some examples

This is my code:

```
'use strict';

var keypress = require('keypress');

// Make `process.stdin` begin emitting "keypress" events
keypress(process.stdin);

// Listening for the "keypress" event
process.stdin.on('keypress', function (ch, key) {
    if (key.name == 'e') {
        console.log('Emergency landing!');
    };  

    if (key.name == 'l') {
        console.log('Landing...');
    }

    if (key.name == 'x') {
        console.log('Goodbye!');
        process.exit();
    }
});

process.stdin.setRawMode(true);
process.stdin.resume();
```

This works if I press letters, but crashes with numbers and other chars.

```
/Users/napolux/rollingspider/rs-1.js:16
    if (key.name == 'e') {
           ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at ReadStream.<anonymous> (/Users/napolux/rollingspider/rs-1.js:16:9)
    at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    at ReadStream.emit (events.js:172:7)
    at emitKey (/Users/napolux/rollingspider/node_modules/keypress/index.js:406:12)
    at ReadStream.onData (/Users/napolux/rollingspider/node_modules/keypress/index.js:48:14)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at ReadStream.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:146:16)
    at ReadStream.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:110:10)
    at TTY.onread (net.js:523:20)
```

Why does this error happen?

How can I allow only certain chars or at least not crash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed.

I was not checking if the `key` object was there... For example:

```
if (key && key.name == 'x') {
    console.log('Goodbye!');
    process.exit();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to read characters would be

```
process.stdin.on('readable', function() {
  var chunk = process.stdin.read();
    if (chunk !== null) {
      process.stdout.write('data: ' + chunk);
    }
});
```

From [Nodejs.org](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_stdin)

The error happens because key is probably 'undefined' and does not contain the property name.